# Flutter Custom Calendar with User Inputted Data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, user-input, flutter-widget

I am attempting to make a journaling and mental health app. I want to have a screen with a calendar that shows color-coded circles (colors are dependent on the selected mood) for each day a user uploads an entry (I have included an image for reference). When the user selects a specific date, I'd like for the user to be able to see their inputted data as well. I'm not sure where to start honestly, so I'm looking for suggestions people have about possible packages, widgets, advice, etc. on what I should do to start building this specific screen:

**Reference Image:**

[image: Example image:]

Thank you and I look forward to hearing your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker

Use selection type add multiple. There are various styling options too

```dart
void _onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
  // TODO: implement your code here
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SfDateRangePicker(
          onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
          selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```